# Checking whether a shop record exists

Tags: comparative-review, go

I have a method to check if the Id exists in the data or not, for example:

```
func (r *ReviewData) Exist() bool {
    // TODO :  checking the shopID value is nil or not.
    // it is a good way to check the value before go to the execution
    query := fmt.Sprintf(
        `
        SELECT
        'x'
        FROM
        ws_active_seller
        WHERE
        shop_id = %d
        `,
        r.ShopID,
    )

    result := postgres.QueryRow(query)
    var data []uint8
    result.Scan(&data)

    if len(data) < 1 {
        return false
    }

    if data[0] != 'x' {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Notice here that I'm not using any parameters to pass into method here.
But There is another approach to do this with :

```
func (r *ReviewData) Exist(shpoID int64) bool {
    // TODO :  checking the shopID value is nil or not.
    // it is a good way to check the value before go to the execution
    query := fmt.Sprintf(
        `
        SELECT
        'x'
        FROM
        ws_active_seller
        WHERE
        shop_id = %d
        `,
        shopID,
    )
    // the rest is the same 
}
```

The different with two method above is the parameters. I would like to know what's a good practice for this.

Any ideas on what can be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go you have a choice as to whether you treat structs like an object with its own methods, and you have an object-oriented feel to your code, or you treat data like parameters, and you pass the data around in a more procedural format. Let's look at your first method first.

The `ReviewData` struct is a struct, and you've declared a method on it that has no parameters. The data required in the method comes from the instance of the struct itself, `r.ShopID`. The logic there is clear (as an aside .... semantically it's a bit ambiguous because, if you have an `r` instance, it seems like it should `Exist`... it's a bit odd to see logic like `if abc.Exists() {...` because if `abc` did not exist it seems like `abc` should be `nil` ;-)

Regardless, your first version of the code looks very natural to me if you're treating the `ReviewData` as an "object" with an object-oriented perspective.

The second version of the code is flawed in its current state. The problem is that the second version has the signature:

> ```
> func (r *ReviewData) Exist(shpoID int64) bool {
> ```

but, inside the function, you never use `r`. Why is it a method on an instance that you never use the instance's data for? It should be just:

```
func Exist(shopID int64) bool {
```

(**NB:** I changed the spelling to be correct... you really should make sure the code works before submitting it to Code Review - broken code is frowned on, and code that does not compile is very frustrating. It could not have compiled with `shpoID` instead of `shopID`)

Anyway, the second version is good as a `static` type of procedure/function, instead of an object instance-based method.

So, depending on how you use the code, the general structure of other methods on `ReviewData`, and the business logic about whether you create an instance of `ReviewData` before the `shopID` exists, or not, determines whether you use the method based version (the first one), or the function version (the second one).

If you store the `shopID` on the `ReviewData` instance (and in no other places), then its better to use the first mechanism. If the shop ID is used in multiple places then it may be best to have a package for shops themselves, and then you code could look like `if shops.Exists(id) ....` (which is the second version).

Bottom line, the right solution depends on how your data is encapsulated, and how you reuse the code.

Comment: Okay I got it know thank you. By the way should I include the link for the full code? I post the snippet of the code in order to show my issue. So it is faster. the link : https://github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang/tree/mock-sql